# AWS EC2のCPUCreditBalanceが25でも、遅くなるのですか？

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

## 環境

- AWS EC2 ts.xlarge

## 背景

t2.xlargeインスタンスで、1日以上かかるバッチプログラムを実行しています。
プログラム開始してから数時間経った後の進捗率は、プログラム開始直後の約2～3倍でした。

進捗率が低いときの、CPUCreditBalanceのグラフは、以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
"25"付近を上下しています。"0"にはなっていません。

グラフの範囲を3日にしたのが、以下の図です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
プログラムが遅くなったタイミングと、CPUCreditBalanceが"1300"から降下して"25"になったタイミングは、同じでした。

以上のことから、「プログラムが遅くなった原因はCPUCreditBalanceだ」と判断しました。

## 質問

CPUCreditBalanceが"0"にならないのは、なぜでしょうか？
また、CPUCreditBalanceが"25"で遅くなるのは、なぜでしょうか？

私は「CPUCreditBalanceが"0"になると、遅くなる」と考えていたので、上記の現象を疑問に思いました。

Comment: 「CPUCreditBalanceが25に降下した」タイミングでいっきに進捗率が低下したのでしょうか？だんだん低下していったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

よくわからないので回答になってないですが・・・

> CPUCreditBalanceが"0"にならないのは、なぜでしょうか？
>   また、CPUCreditBalanceが"25"で遅くなるのは、なぜでしょうか？

t2.xlarge は 4vCPU なので、5分間で 最大20クレジット消費する事ができます。
なので グラフの 値が "0" にならなくても速度の低下は見られると思います。
しかしながら 下限が24以上あるので もう少し動いてくれても良い気がしますね・・・。

この程度は 誤差なのかもしれませんが、他にボトルネックがある可能性は排除できない気がします。